# List of subappendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have subappendices within each chapter using the `subappendices` command from the `appendix`.
I have the appendices show up in my table of contents within each chapter as follows.

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}
```

```
Chapter 1
 Section 1.1
 Section 1.2

 Appendices
 Appendix 1.A

Chapter 2
```

How can I create a list of appendices in a separate page (similar to list of figures and tables)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

[toclotf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) lets you create custom lists of counters used in a document. I would recommend to get familiar with the package even though a solution is within the `appendix` package.

As an example, here's the code with a custom counter `subappendix`, which is used in a new list of appendices. You can print the list either on the current or a new page if you append `\clearpage` before \listof...`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistof[chapter]{subappendix}{apx}{List of Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{Appendix \thechapter.\Alph{subappendix}}
\newcommand\appx[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{subappendix}%
    \section*{\thesubappendix\enspace#1}%
    \addcontentsline{apx}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix} #1}\par}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{7em}

\title{The title}
\author{First Last}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofsubappendix

\chapter{The first chapter}
\kant[9][1]
\section{A regular section}
\kant[10]
\section{Another regular section}
\kant[11]
\appx{This is an appendix}
\kant[1]
\appx{This is another appendix}
\kant[2]

\chapter{The second chapter}
\kant[11][1]
\section{A regular section}
\kant[12]
\section{Another regular section}
\kant[13]
\appx{This is an appendix in another chapter}
\kant[3]
\appx{This is another appendix}
\kant[4]
\appx{This is the last appendix}
\kant[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]